# retrieve the email address from radio button data source options

Tags: c#, .net, smtp, radio-button, datasource

I have radio buttons from which I can select the type of data source to retrieve the email addresses of recipients.

```
  if (RadioButton1.Checked)
{
    sql.Open();
    string s = "select * from address";
    SqlCommand t = new SqlCommand(s, sql);
    t.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sql.Close();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT address FROM address1";
    cmd.Connection = sql;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    sql.Open();
    da.Fill(dt);
    sql.Close();

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        Msg.To.Add(row["address"].ToString());
    }
}
else if (RadioButton2.Checked)
{
    string connectionString = "";
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        string fileLocation = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + fileName);
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(fileLocation);

        if (fileExtension == ".xls")
        {
            connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
        }
        else if (fileExtension == ".xlsx")
        {
            connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
        }
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        con.Open();
        DataTable dtExcelSheetName = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
        string getExcelSheetName = dtExcelSheetName.Rows[0]["Table_Name"].ToString();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT address FROM [" + getExcelSheetName + "]";
        dAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
        dAdapter.Fill(dt);
        con.Close();


        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            Msg.To.Add(row["address"].ToString());
        }
    }
}
else if (RadioButton3.Checked)
{
    if (FileUpload2.HasFile)
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload2.PostedFile.FileName);

        string fileLocation = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + fileName);
        FileUpload2.SaveAs(fileLocation);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileLocation);
        String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
        string[] toAddressArray;
        toAddressArray = line.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
        foreach (string a in toAddressArray)
        {
            Msg.To.Add(a);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, what I want is when the recipient clicks the link in the html page which I have sent as mail body, I want to retrieve the mail id of the recipient which is from one of the three radio button data source options.
How to get the mail id?
Here is the complete code:

```
SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mystring"].ConnectionString);

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    getFiles();
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        var list = getFiles();
        dd1.DataSource = list;
        dd1.DataTextField = "Key";
        dd1.DataValueField = "Value";
        dd1.DataBind();
    }
}
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    {
        SendHTMLMail();
    }

    void SendHTMLMail()
    {


        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dd1.SelectedItem.Value);
        string readFile = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Regex regx = new Regex("(?<!src=\")http(s)?://([\\w+?\\.\\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\\~\\!\\@\\#\\$\\%\\^\\&amp;\\*\\(\\)_\\-\\=\\+\\\\\\/\\?\\.\\:\\;\\'\\,]*([a-zA-Z0-9\\?\\#\\=\\/]){1})?", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        string output = regx.ToString();
        string count = 0.ToString();
        output = readFile;
        string username = Server.UrlEncode(this.txtUsername.Text);
        output = regx.Replace(output, new MatchEvaluator((match) =>
        {
            var url = Uri.EscapeDataString(match.Value.ToString());
            return $"http://localhost:61187/two?sender={username}&link={url}&count={count}";
        }));


        MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();

        Msg.From = new MailAddress(txtUsername.Text);


        Msg.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
        Msg.Body = output.ToString();
        Msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

        if (fuAttachment.HasFile)
        {
            string FileName = Path.GetFileName(fuAttachment.PostedFile.FileName);
            Msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(fuAttachment.PostedFile.InputStream, FileName));
        }
        if (RadioButton1.Checked)
        {
            sql.Open();
            string s = "select * from address";
            SqlCommand t = new SqlCommand(s, sql);
            t.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sql.Close();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT address FROM address1";
            cmd.Connection = sql;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            sql.Open();
            da.Fill(dt);
            sql.Close();

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                Msg.To.Add(row["address"].ToString());
            }
        }
        else if (RadioButton2.Checked)
        {
            string connectionString = "";
            if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                string fileLocation = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + fileName);
                FileUpload1.SaveAs(fileLocation);

                if (fileExtension == ".xls")
                {
                    connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                }
                else if (fileExtension == ".xlsx")
                {
                    connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                }
                OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                con.Open();
                DataTable dtExcelSheetName = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                string getExcelSheetName = dtExcelSheetName.Rows[0]["Table_Name"].ToString();
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT address FROM [" + getExcelSheetName + "]";
                dAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
                dAdapter.Fill(dt);
                con.Close();


                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    Msg.To.Add(row["address"].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        else if (RadioButton3.Checked)
        {
            if (FileUpload2.HasFile)
            {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload2.PostedFile.FileName);

                string fileLocation = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + fileName);
                FileUpload2.SaveAs(fileLocation);
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileLocation);
                String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
                string[] toAddressArray;
                toAddressArray = line.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
                foreach (string a in toAddressArray)
                {
                    Msg.To.Add(a);
                }
            }
        }

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(txtUsername.Text, txtpwd.Text);
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.Send(Msg);
        Msg = null;
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "alert('Email sent.');", true);
    }
}

public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> getFiles()
{
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/App_Data"));
    var fi = di.EnumerateFiles("*.html", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
    var files = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    foreach (FileInfo file in fi)
    {
        files.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(file.Name, file.FullName));
    }
    return files;
}
```

Comment: I don't see "mail id" anywhere in your code.  How are we supposed to know where it is?

Comment: It's unclear.. How is the radio button in a mail related to the mail address of the recipent of a mail?
The mail body is a text either it has the information or it doesn't.
You won't be able to have code executed in the mail, no js or c# or what ever. Either your link has the information, Mailaddress or an id. Or the link don't have that information there is try. Mail are static plain Html.

Comment: i have edited and posted the complete code @rory.ap

Comment: i have edited and posted the complete code @DragandDrop   and radio button is used just to select the list of recipients to whom mail would be sent

Comment: now provide the solution @DragandDrop

Comment: now provide the solution @rory.ap